# Sending email with OAuth authentication to Office 365 using MgGraph

Tags: powershell, oauth, azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I'm trying to send emails using MgGraph and Modern Authentication and somehow this fails.

The sender receives an auto-respond from Exchange saying;

*Diagnostic information for administrators:
Generating server: AS8PR08MB9314.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com
Remote server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP.*

Let me explain what I'm doing;

I have a script that is using Graph API to send the email. This script is authenticating with a certificate (self-signed on my laptop and added to the App Registration earlier) on an AD Application that has Graph API Mail.Send permissions.

The Graph POST is successful, but Exchange immediately sends back the above NDR.

```
Install-Module MSAL.PS
Import-Module MSAL.PS

$appName = "MailSendingTestApp"
$appRegistration = @{
    TenantId          = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    ClientId          = "\<app-id\>"
    ClientCertificate = (Get-ChildItem Cert:\\CurrentUser\\My | Where-Object {$\_.Subject -eq ('CN={0}' -f $appName)})
}

$msalToken = Get-MsalToken @appRegistration -ForceRefresh -AzureCloudInstance 1

$fromEmailAddress = "email address removed for privacy reasons"
$requestBody = @{
    "message"         = \[PSCustomObject\]@{
        "subject"      = "OAuth Mail Test"
        "body"         = \[PSCustomObject\]@{
            "contentType" = "Text"
            "content"     = "Hello this is a test"
        }
        "toRecipients" = @(
            \[PSCustomObject\]@{
                "emailAddress" = \[PSCustomObject\]@{
                    "address" = "email address removed for privacy reasons"
                }
            }
        )
    }
"saveToSentItems" = "true"
}

$request = @{
    "Headers"     = @{Authorization = $msalToken.CreateAuthorizationHeader() }
    "Method"      = "Post"
    "Uri"         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$fromEmailAddress/sendMail"
    "Body"        = $requestBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
    "ContentType" = "application/json"
}

Invoke-RestMethod @request
```

Googling led me to a post that links to a MS article that says; "This error can happen when you are trying out a Microsoft 365 trial tenant. If you receive this error before you can purchase licenses, contact support to request an exception for the low reputation IP address until you're able to purchase licenses."

My tenant is licensed with Microsoft 365 E5 Developer (part of the Visual Studio benefit that comes with our partner account).

What could be going wrong here? Do I need to contact Microsoft here or start pulling my wallet?

Hope someone can help.

**Update May, 19th 2023**

*Thanks everyone for helping out, but I just confirmed this to be a problem related to having a Developer license.
As soon as I try this on a production tenant with licenses it immediately works and mails are received by the intended recipient.
It seems Microsoft has some kind of protection to prevent misuse of trial and developer accounts.
A good thing, but not helpful if you want to test something conceptually before putting it in production.*

Comment: The error says : "traffic not accepted from this IP".  You are testing from a different tenant IP than you customer. Email the credentials for the "From" Address and the email account must match.  You are using different credentials.  Try your code with your tenant credentials.

Comment: What I would expect is that I am posting a request to the Graph API which is accepted. I can do the POST from any location.
Then the Graph API's SMTP services (somewhere in the world of Microsoft) will go ahead and try to send the email to Exchange Online, which in turn would need to deliver this to the intended recipient.
If Exchange Online already rejects the email that is being delivered by the API, then Graph's servers would not be trusted by Exchange Online. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also the credentials to the Graph API are using the AD App Registration, not with user credentials. I want to prevent having to login with credentials in the script. This is what the new Modern Authentication in Exchange should be all about.

Comment: There are different types of authentication : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods?force_isolation=true